# Securing Web API with SPA code

Tags: security, rest, asp.net-web-api, authorization, single-page-application

I'm developing a rich client javascript application with ASP MVC 4 Web API back end.

How would you suggest to secure all the ajax requests ad make sure they are made from an authenticated user.

Thanks !

Comment: Have you looked at the asp.net's webapi site on security?  If not, you should check it out.  There are several options detailed: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security  There is no clear best choice ... it depends on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Any securing mechanism would do, consider for example Forms authentication.
You add the Authorize attribute to your controller methods and ajax requests carry the cookie if it has been issued from the server.

This is really as simple. If for some reason it doesn't apply to your scenario, you'd have to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

As Wiktor suggested, you could use Form-based authentication (HTTP mechanism).

If we consider your question more broadly though, what does it mean to *secure* all the AJAX requests?

You probably want to achieve:

- integrity
- confidentiality
- non repudiation
- accountability
- more?

The topic is more broadly discussed on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_security). More specifically you want to do the following in your API:

- secure the communication channel: use SSL (either one-way or 2-way). This will provide integrity and confidentiality
- use authentication. This will give you non-repudiation and accountability. There are different authentication methods available in .NET (Forms, HTTP Basic, SAML-based...)
- for advanced scenarios around authorization (which user is allowed to call with method), use claims-based authorization (part of .NET framework), RBAC, or XACML.